# incorrect replace() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this replace function, but it doesn't implement any changes. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
energy['Country'].replace({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea','United States of America':'United States','United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom','China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region':'Hong Kong'})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [read the documentation of functions you use if you do not know how they work](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) - it RETURNS modified data. It does not modify in place.

Comment: many thanks, understand now. Appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, the function does implement changes, they just don't get stored anywhere. Maybe try this:

```py
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].replace({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea','United States of America':'United States','United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom','China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region':'Hong Kong'})
```